# Как узнать путь до папки, имея только название этой папки

Tags: python, ос

`project_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())`
Эта строка узнает путь до текущего рабочего каталога.
Что делать если мне нужно узнать путь до конкертной папки?

Comment: Ну только поиском наверное через `glob.glob` или `os.walk` обойти все папки и найти нужную

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+os.walk)